# neo4j: label parameters on section hops only?

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to constrict the type of labels within unlimited hop sections of a pattern? And how would you implement that within a larger pattern?

```
WITH n, end
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Label1)<-[:REL2]-(a:Label2)-[:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*..]->(b)<-[:REL3]-(:Label3)->(end:Label1)
WITH b, ... continue
```

I'd like the section  between a and b to only include nodes of a certain label.

```
WITH n, end
 OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Label1)<-[:REL2]-(a:Label2)-[:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*..]->(b)<-[:REL3]-(:Label3)->(end:Label1), 
p=(a)-[:CONSTRICT_REL_LABEL*..]->(b) WHERE nodes(p):Label
WITH b, ... continue
```

Is there a way to do this?

```
   WITH n, end
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Label1)<-[:REL2]-(a:Label2)-[:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*..]->(b)<-[:REL3]-(:Label3)->(end:Label1), 
    p=(a)-[:CONSTRICT_REL_LABEL*..]->(b) 
   WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(p) WHERE node:Label)
   WITH b, ...continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `nodes(path)` is a list of nodes, you can use index access to get the relevant slice of the nodes in the path, and use that for your filtering:

```
...
WITH n, end
OPTIONAL MATCH path = (n:Label1)<-[:REL2]-(a:Label2)-[:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*..]->(b)<-[:REL3]-(c:Label3)-[:REL4]->(end:Label1), 
WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(path)[2..-3] WHERE node:Label)
WITH b, ...
...
```

`nodes(path)[0..2]` is `[n, a]`, so if you wanted the nodes past `a` (but not including `a` itself), you would start at 2.

Negative indexes are elements from the end of the list, so the `-3` means it will exclude the last 3 elements of the list, including `[b, c, end]`.

If you wanted to include `a` as well as `b`, then your slice would be `nodes(path)[1..-2]` instead

Comment: Just to note, the label check will be a filtering operation after the path is found, it will not be checked during path expansion.

Comment: Would it be faster to restructure and rely on rel.property check? eg [rel:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*..] WHERE rel.boolean?

or does this make any sense? - [:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*0..1] -(:Label)- [:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*0..1] -(:Label)- [:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*0..1] -(:Label)- [:CONSTRICT_HOPS_TO_LABEL*0..1] 

Sorry - I'm brainstorming here... thanks!

Comment: This is not going to work. ;o( Filtering adds ridiculous amount of time to the query. It looks like I will need to restructure with a different relationship type altogether to make this feasible...